# Using a PNG file as an interactive map in pygame

Tags: maps, pygame

I am working with pygame. I want to build a 2D scrolling game. I don't want to have to program all the necessary rects in order to make my large map. Is it possible to use a png file (which would be the map) and have a sprite interact with any part of the image as if it were a rect? or import and convert the image into rects? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "interact" you're referring mostly to collision detection (i.e. controlling where on the map a character can and cannot move). That's a very broad topic with lots of resources available.

Look into the `pygame.mask` module [(docs here)](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html). To do what you're describing, you could create separate mask images by overlaying your levels with e.g. one color for areas that cannot be passed through and another for areas that can. Then `pygame.mask.from_threshold()` could automatically create a `Mask` object that you can use to detect collisions between sprites and the level.

As a very simple example, consider this Mario level:

[image: Mario level example]

A collision mask might look like this:

[image: Mario level mask example]

Note that the boxes aren't accounted for on the mask despite being "part of the level;"  this approach is only really useful for completely static pieces of a level. The boxes would probably be a sprite with their own rect/mask to detect collisions. In this case, the pipe would be only a solid object.

Also note that one large image for an entire level with a complex mask would likely lead to performance problems. In my experience scrolling a large image is not something Pygame does well.

**tl;dr** - It's possible (to some extent), but won't be performance-friendly.